# Gradle how to exclude 1 test file in a multi module project setup?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, gradle, junit, build.gradle

So we have a multi module project setup, with test all scattered in multiple modules, now we want to execute all of them but exclude 1 test file.

How could we achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
gradle test -PexcludeTests=*SpecificTests
```

but the tests get still executed.

for running a singular test I managed to fix it this way:

```
gradle :multi-module:test --tests '*SpecificTests'
```

but unfortunately the equivalent for executing all tests but 1 cannot be made with this.

**Condition:** we need a command we cannot use the testing filter

Comment: WRT your condition: Can you edit the build script at all?

Comment: @user16358266 we can but the problem is that, we need this execution separation for pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can use a project property and define an optional exclude filter, which you can then use from the command line `-PexcludeTests='*SpecificTests'`.

```
test {

  if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
    exclude(project.property('excludeTests'))
  }

}
```

Comment: either I am doing something wrong or this does not work well in a multi-module Gradle setup. i added this and then I ran my pipeline but the tests still get executed

Comment: i also got error because i could not add it to the build.gradle of the root project